# Allowing a while to run every X ms

Tags: c++, windows, delay

I'm trying to make my while loop run every 10 ms. The code inside the while is pretty simple, so it doesn't take significant time to run. Is there any other way besides using the `Sleep()` function at the end of the while? Something more accurate?

I'm using Visual Studio.

Comment: Why 10ms? The default windows timer resolution is 15.6 ms. Why do you need more? Are you trying to control an animation perhaps? That's *not* the correct way to handle multimedia

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `std::this_thread::sleep_for`, it is best to use `sleep_until` for this type of delay.  This will automatically take into account how long the other code inside the loop is taking (however trivial or not):

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto next = steady_clock::now();
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "hi\n";
        next += 10ms;
        std::this_thread::sleep_until(next);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say, that this should be accurate enough. If you want to have the code run exactly every 10ms, then you have to measure length of execution of the code and then do Sleep for `10ms - <length of execution in ms>`.

For measuring with best precision you can use high_resolution_clock from , which runs at least at system_clock rate, or better.  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/high_resolution_clock/

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can use [SetTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906(v=vs.85).aspx).

However, that might be overcomplicating things - especially if your callback needs access to a class. You should check out [std::this_thread::sleep_for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for)

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
```

Comment: Sleeping can't guarantee that something will be executed every 10 seconds. Windows timers have a default precision of 15.6ms and even then, thread switching may cause delays

Comment: Good point, I didn't know about the default precision - do you happen to have a link where I can read about this?

Answer (score 0):

if you do need to run it exactly every 10 ms, better wait in spin loop. pseudocode:

```
while (your_condition)
{
    var t = curTime;
    do_what_you_need;
    while (curTime - t < 10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `Sleep` and [Waitable Timers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms687012(v=vs.85).aspx) use threading behind the scenes, so the resolution is in the order of the default time slice, which is 10-20ms. If you need higher resolution, you should look into Multimedia Timers. [The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd742877(v=vs.85).aspx) promises better than 1ms resolution. The `SetTimer`/`WM_TIMER` interface on the hand seems to have a fixed resolution of  15.6ms, as others have said.

Another high resolution timing interface is [Performance Counter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373083(v=vs.85).aspx), but it seems you can only query them, not wait on anything, so you would have idle waiting loops (spinning) with them.